# Confirm before executing Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want a popup asking if I want to proceed before executing the javascript code itself.
The problem is I can't change the button itself to add a confirm thing.
The code I use is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function confirmclick(id) {
var answer = confirm ('This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to perform this action?');
if (answer) {
<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("button span:contains('Sendung übermitteln')").parent("button").click(function(){
jQuery(this).unbind('click');
});
jQuery("button span:contains('Sendung übermitteln')").parent("button").click();

});
//]]>
} else{} }
</script>
```

At the moment nothing happens. No pop-up and no clicking on the button...

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your function to a DOM load event, so that it is called when the page is ready.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do some stuff, call your function etc
});
```

Then that code will be called when the page loads. Alternatively if you want it at another time, change the event that triggers the callback above.

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in this code.

1. `<![CDATA[` should go after `<script type="text/javascript">` and `//]]>` before `</script>`.
2. Ensure that you bind the click event on the button to the `confirmclick` function. e.g. add `$(document).ready(function() { $('#you_btn_id').onclick(confirmclick); });` before `</script>`. Remove `jQuery("button span:contains('Sendung übermitteln')").parent("button").click();` because it triggers the click event. It is not intended to bind an event.
3. Remove `jQuery(document).ready` because it isn't necessary: the confirmclick function will be called only after the document is loaded. Furthermore, if you live it there your callback function will never be executed because the document has already been loaded and the event already triggered.